# Unzip file not working

Tags: java, android, unzip

I want to unzip a zip file on android. I searched and found this code; I tried to implement it without success. Would somebody be able to tell me why? I can't seem to find the problem.

I copy the `main.zip` file on the sdcard, but after I run program, I can't find the `unzipFile` folder on the sdcard. Why does this behavior occur?

And another thing, if I want to unzip file of asset folder, how can i get path of this file in asset and save this path in String variable? Thanks.

```
public class Decompress { 
  private String _zipFile; 
  private String _location; 

  public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
    _zipFile = zipFile; 
    _location = location; 

    _dirChecker(""); 
  } 

  public void unzip() { 
    try  { 
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ZipEntry ze = null; 
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
        Log.e("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

        if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
          _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
        } else { 
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
          for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
            fout.write(c); 
          } 

          zin.closeEntry(); 
          fout.close(); 
        } 

      } 
      zin.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    } 

  } 

  private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
    File f = new File(_location + dir); 

    if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
      f.mkdirs(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

**main.java:**

```
public class UnZipFile extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.e("he", "heee");
    Toast.makeText(this, "in activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String zipFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/main.zip";// "file:///android_asset/main.zip";
    String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/unzipFile/";
    Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation);
    d.unzip();

}
 }
```

manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Consider rewording `And another thing, if I want to unzip file of asset folder, how can i get path of this file in asset and save this path in String variable?`. Extremely difficult to understand.

Comment: Questions with the core message: "I tried to use this code, here it is, and why isn't it working for me?":  need to ruthlessly downvoted, closed, and deleted by moderators. Not salvaged. Don't say: "It isn't working".  These types of questions harm stackoverflow by filling it up with nonsense:  "Here's a Copy Paste of code, why doesn't it work for me?  It's infuriating because there are an infinite number of reasons why that could be.  We're not here to play the game '20 questions' with you. Tell us what you did, tell us what you have, tell us what you expected, and then tell us what you got.

Comment: My question is clear, The Playtypus, I mean, I have a zip file in asset folder, and i want access to this file for unzip. how can i get path of this file of asset folder? Is this clear or not? Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can't access to sd card. You check this, with create a file and check for exist this.

Comment: Oh, this is true, I should remove access to storage of my phone and then i try for access to sd card with my app. Thanks. Do you know how can i access to a zip file of asset folder and unzip this?